# Java inheritance reference

Tags: java

```
class SuperClass{
    int num=10;
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    int num=20;
}

public class TestClass{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       SuperClass s1 = new SuperClass();
       SuperClass s2 = new SubClass();
       System.out.println(s2.num); // displays 10
   }
```

}

Object s2 points to subclass. Why does it display 10?

Comment: Because member variables are not polymorphic.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override fields, only methods.

When you watch s2 in the debugger, you will see two fields num there.
One from the super one from the subclass.

You could add a method getNum() in both classes one returning 10 the other 20 and call this.
Tham it will work as expected.